# Why do my SQLite commands not work on my Server?

Tags: php, sqlite

I've been trying to get my SQLite Script working on a Server, it worked perfectly on my Local Machine, but I can't get it working. I already installed the SQLite Drivers and the rest of my script works. But every SQLite Command that should be executed just does - nothing. No error but no editing the data bank. I noticed that on my Local Server the SQLite Library Version is 3.7.17 and on the other Server it is 3.7.9.. Could it have something to do with that? And if yes, how can I install the newer Version?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it! 
It was one of those stupid problems... 
User and group was set to 'root'. As a normal Website-Visitor I ofcourse did not have the needed rights. 
Instead of changing Owner you could probably also change the rights into 777.